# Airflow start multiple concurrent generic tasks

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Trying to get a few tasks concurrently on cloud composer:

```
arr = {}
for i in xrange(3):
    print("i: " + str(i))
    command_formatted = command_template.format(str(i))
    create_training_instance = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='create_training_instance',
        bash_command=command_formatted)
    arr[i] = create_training_instance
    start_training.set_downstream(arr[i])
```

Getting the following error:

> Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/scale_simple.py] Dependency
>   , create_training_instance already
>   registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parameterize your task id as well, e.g., 
task_id='create_training_instance' --> 'create_traiing_instance-{}'.format(i)

Answer (score 1):

The `task_id` should always be unique for a single task. So, you can use something like `create_training_instance_{}.format(i)` as `task_id`.